# merging each tuple with the next one in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, python-zip

I have a list of tuples which looks like this:

```
lst = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
```

I would like to get:

```
list = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h')]
```

I believe it's pretty simple, but I'm stuck unfortunately..

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?? Also, why wasn't `d` merged with `e`?

Comment: It was a mistake, thanks for correcting it, I tried using ```zip```, but it seems like I haven't used it correctly

Comment: `[(a, b), (c, d), (e, f), (g, h)]` -- this is not a correct python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> lst = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h')]
```

`zip(lst, lst[1:])` zips each element with its next neighbour into a `(x, y)` tuple, then we add the tuples together with `x + y`.

Answer (score 2):

Just clean python builins:

```
old_list = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f), (g, h)]

length_of_new_list = len(list) - 1

new_list= []

for i in range(length_of_new_list):
    new_list.append(old_list [i] + old_list [i + 1])
```

As RoadRunner mentioned, you also can do with `zip()`. This will be more fast.

Comment: A list should not be called `list`, as it is 'reserved object type'.

Comment: It works though even with name `list`, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think should work :D

```
myList= [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
newList = []
for i in range(0, len(myList)-1, 1):
    newList += ([myList[i] + myList[i+1]])

print(newList)
```

Using zip is also a good idea.
EDIT: Based on comments below
-Fixed the "bug"(that skips some combinations)
-changed var "list" to "myList"

Comment: A list should not be called `list`, it is the name of an  object, not a variable, so it can be confusing.

Comment: Still good one, but it gives `[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h')]` without `('c', 'd', 'e', 'f')` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way

```
list1 = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
length = len(list1)
res = []
for i in range(length-1):
    res.append(list1[i] + list1[i+1])

print(res)
```

output:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h')]
```